# Asynchronous call ends after calling function ends

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following method, and I need the asynchronous task called inside it to finish before the method:

```
  func checkForLoggedInUser() {
    self.isAuthenticating = true
    Task {
      if await dataManager.isUserLogged() {
        do {
          self.loggedInUser = try await dataManager.fetchMe()
        } catch {
          self.error = error
        }
      }
      self.isAuthenticating = false
    }
  }
```

This isn't happening.
Adding some console prints this is the result:

```
  func checkForLoggedInUser() {
    self.isAuthenticating = true
    print("1")
    Task {
      print("2")
      if await dataManager.isUserLogged() {
        print("3")
        do {
          print("4")
          self.loggedInUser = try await dataManager.fetchMe()
        } catch {
          print("5")
          self.error = error
        }
        print("6")
      }
      print("7")
      self.isAuthenticating = false
    }
    print("8")
  }
```

Result: `1,8,2,3,4,6,7`

Comment: That just isn't how asynchronous *works*.  While you can use something like a `DispatchSemaphore` to block execution, you risk deadlocks and it kind of defeats the point of asynchronous execution.  Your `checkForLoggedInUser` should be an `async` function and the caller should `await` it.

Comment: Semaphores not only defeat the purpose `async`-`await`, but are actually unsafe to use in that context (and will generate errors in the future). TheKingArthas, don't even contemplate that pattern. As Paulw11 said, just embrace asynchronous programming patterns.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Task` you are effectively telling it to go off and do something else while your code continues.

You should make your function itself `async` then you don’t need it to run off and perform a separate `Task`.

```
func checkForLoggedInUser() async {
self.isAuthenticating = true
  if await dataManager.isUserLogged() {
    do {
```